# Reinstalling phpmyadmin as I did not select apache2 in server selection

Tags: server, phpmyadmin, linux-kernel, apache2, ubuntu-16.04

I was installing phpmyadmin on my ubuntu 16.04. when I was asked to select a server selection, I had by mistake, not selected apache2, and the installer had already completed...
I have already tried uninstalling by apt-get remove phpmyadmin, and tried reinstalling but this time, I wasn't asked about the server selection...what do I do? 
Ps:if its relevant, I have webmin installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove phpmyadmin
```

Comment: Although this code snippet may answer the question, including an explanation of *why* and *how* it helps solve the problem improves the quality and longevity of your answer. See ["How do I write a good answer?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).